# Allowing more configuration for the Global Inbox

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, notification-bar

As detailed in [this StackExchange blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) the StackExchange Global Inbox has been recently expanded to capture all notifications on the network - including among other things the badge notifications that were formerly shown with the orange banner at the top of the page. It is a **beautiful** change!

However, would it be possible to allow users to configure how they want notifications to appear, toggling certain notification to still use the orange banner? And preferably to allow the selection of both (since the history in the Global Inbox is simply wonderful and I would not like to risk missing it)?

The reason for the request was yesterday I was awarded the Popular Question badge and was a little... underwhelmed... I noticed the beautiful subtle grey notificaiton, clicked on the inbox and saw that I had a new badge. And then shrugged.

In the past I remember seeing the big orange bar for a new badge and being like a little kid at Christmas, so happy to discover what good thing I've done now.

It could be that the orange bar actually had nothing to with that, but I suspect it did.

Another option would be to allow users to choose the status of notifications in the inbox, so I could get my new badge glee back by making badges appear in red.

Comment: So... you want the orange bar back so you can feel like a little kid at Christmas? This seems like a very poor reason for a feature request.

Comment: The badges are there to encourage user activity - if the orange bar enhances that for even 5% of users then allowing it back as a configurable option seems like a good idea. As for the christmas thing, I like to make posts on meta a little more evocative of my feelings.